Proving $\phi(n) \geq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ using Dirichlet series
There are already some posts regarding the proof of the following statement:
$$\forall n\geq 1, \phi(n) \geq \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$$
However, I was wondering if we could find another proof using properties of the Dirichlet series, such as, for $\Re(s)>2$:
$$\sum \dfrac{\phi(n)}{n^s} = \dfrac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}\ \ (*)$$
and then maybe extract information from the coefficients using an integral.
More generally, can we use Dirichlet series to prove inequalities involving arithmetic functions?
Context of this question: using $(*)$, I managed to prove that if the following statement is true for all $n\geq 1$: $$\phi(n) \geq C n$$
with $C\in\mathbb R^+$, then $C=0$.

ugh... This can be proved via elementary method without the series... is this okay?

Just so you know, the primorial numbers (products of consecutive primes beginning with $2$)  are the numbers with surprisingly small $\phi.$   That is, for fixed $\delta > 0,$ the minimum  of $ \frac{\phi(n)}{n^\delta} $  does occur, and the best $n$ is a primorial. This uses "multiplicativeness" of $\phi$  in a critical way: given fixed $\delta,$  we can precisely factor the best $n$  This method was begun by Ramanujan in 1915. Easier, for primorial $n$  the fraction $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ goes to zero as the primorial $n$ goes to infinity
